# android manifest mal formed

Tags: android, android-manifest

I know this is not a real question nor a debugging website but I searched for two hours and I can't find where the error comes from. I got a `Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED]`

So here is my actual manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="PACKAGE_NAME" >

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name=".ConnectActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".ForgetPasswordActivity"
            android:label="@string/activity_forget_password_title" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".ConnectActivity" />
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".ListChampionsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_list_champions" >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".DisplayChampionActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_display_champion" >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".SettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/menu_action_settings" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".ConnectActivity" />
        </activity>

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                   android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
                   android:key="API_KEY" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I obviously replaced the package name and of the api key by some constant but in my code they are correctly filled.

Comment: are there some empty lines before <?xml ... ?

Comment: There is none empty lines before the xml tag

Comment: I'm not sure that using a constant for package name is allowed... But I've never used constant in my manifest, can someone confirm this?

Comment: I don't know if this is the reason but I can't see that you are setting the min and target SDK

Comment: Tr4X I mean I put constant just to remove my sensive data when posting on SO but in my code it is normal strings.
Also I am using Android Studio so it seems that Gradle is handling the sdk versions.

Comment: you replaced your real package with PACKAGE_NAME. Does your real package have a capital letter ?

Comment: not only something like this extension.domain

Comment: Just be sure to use ONLY little letters no capital. Seems you have only little letters so the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Another question. API_KEY should be your custom value. Is that the case or did you simply copy/paste what google give, because they say "Substitute your API key for API_KEY in the value attribute." https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start

Comment: It is the case, I just started to use the google api so I was actually not sure how important it was to keep the key secret so in case I replaced it by API_KEY on StackOverflow to be safe.

Comment: I re-read your manifest file more in details like ten times. I really cannot see what is wrong.

Comment: Yeah I don't see anything wrong either, this is why I allowed myself posting about manifest file here.. I am wondering if this is not related to some other files but... No warning or anything beside this message.

Comment: Did you try to remove various parts of manifest (especially `<meta-data>` items) to localize the problem?

Comment: Just tried, so I am able to compile but the application instantly crash when I launch it

Answer (score 0):

Do these steps :

- try change name package with Caps letters to little letters.
- Provide  `package_name.Class_name` inside activity.

Answer (score 0):

I finally fixed my problem writing :

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="API_KEY" />
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:key="API_KEY" />
```